# How to merge multiple Backbone collection divs into one (To fix the HTML layout)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, backbone.js

I am working on a backbone collection view. Collections are shown as rows using a div. Each row contains child views (cells).

My problem is, I need to make it appear as if there's only one collection, that is, the cells will be merged together into a single parent div. Please see my illustration below:

[image: Illustration]

Markup:

```
<div class="team-container container" data-view="Sports.View">
   <div class="team-row clearfix" data-view="Athletes.View">
      <div class="col-sm-8 team-row">
         <h1><a href="#">Surf</a></h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 team-cell">
         <div class="va-container-anchor">
            <div class="feat-image"><img src="http://us.billabong.sb1.sandbox.netsuitestaging.com/assets-bbg/images/content/laura-enever.jpg" alt="" class="fit-team-image"></div>
            <div class="va-container-hover">
               <a href="/team/laura-enever" data-hashtag="#team/laura-enever" class="holder">
                  <div class="content">
                     <div class="text"> Laura Enever </div>
                  </div>
               </a>
            </div>
            <div class="copy-block">
               <small>Pro Surf</small>
               <h2>Laura Enever</h2>
               <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" href="/team/laura-enever" data-hashtag="#team/laura-enever">Explore</a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 team-cell">
         <div class="va-container-anchor">
            <div class="feat-image"><img src="/images/content/laura-enever.jpg" alt="" class="fit-team-image"></div>
            <div class="va-container-hover">
               <a href="/team/laura-enever-2" data-hashtag="#team/laura-enever-2" class="holder">
                  <div class="content">
                     <div class="text"> Laura Enever </div>
                  </div>
               </a>
            </div>
            <div class="copy-block">
               <small>Pro Surf</small>
               <h2>Laura Enever</h2>
               <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" href="/team/laura-enever-2" data-hashtag="#team/laura-enever-2">Explore</a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 team-cell">
         <div class="va-container-anchor">
            <div class="feat-image"><img src="/images/content/courtney_conlogue_profile.jpg" alt="" class="fit-team-image"></div>
            <div class="va-container-hover">
               <a href="/team/courtney-conlogue" data-hashtag="#team/courtney-conlogue" class="holder">
                  <div class="content">
                     <div class="text"> Courtney Conlogue </div>
                  </div>
               </a>
            </div>
            <div class="copy-block">
               <small>Pro Surf</small>
               <h2>Courtney Conlogue</h2>
               <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" href="/team/courtney-conlogue" data-hashtag="#team/courtney-conlogue">Explore</a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="team-row clearfix" data-view="Athletes.View">
      <div class="col-sm-8 team-row">
         <h1><a href="#">Snow</a></h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 team-cell">
         <div class="va-container-anchor">
            <div class="feat-image"><img src="/images/content/helen_profile.jpg" alt="" class="fit-team-image"></div>
            <div class="va-container-hover">
               <a href="/team/helen-schettini" data-hashtag="#team/helen-schettini" class="holder">
                  <div class="content">
                     <div class="text"> Helen Schettini </div>
                  </div>
               </a>
            </div>
            <div class="copy-block">
               <small>Pro Snow</small>
               <h2>Helen Schettini</h2>
               <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" href="/team/helen-schettini" data-hashtag="#team/helen-schettini">Explore</a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is actually a bootstrap question. You should tag bootstrap... BTW why is there repeated markup? Isn't it supposed to be dynamically generated? Could you reduce it to just the actual thing?

Comment: Also it is not clear which is the markup for collection view, which is the markup for child view, how the collection view template gets repeated etc....